# ClassCastException when using FragmentTabHost

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I am using [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html) with android support library,

My layout file **sub_main.xml**:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

The above layout is used in my fragment:

```
   public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
       ...
       private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
       private View content;

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_main, null); 

            // the following code throw ClassCastException, why?
            mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) content.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

            return content;
        }
   ...
}
```

But, I got the **ClassCastException** exception in the above code where `mTabHost` is initialized in onCreateView() :

```
07-03 16:35:09.704: E/AndroidRuntime(25350): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TabHost cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
```

It complains that `TabHost` can not be cast to `FragmentTabHost`, why & how to get rid of it. Thanks.

Comment: why are you looking for android.R.id.tabhost if the root of your layout is alread the TabHost ?  FragmentTabHost content = (FragmentTabHost) inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_main, null); or mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) content; ??

Comment: @ blackbelt, even though I changed to directly assign the root view to mTabHost variable, I still get the same exception.

Comment: did try try to clean and rebuild your project? Also check that MyFragment imports come all from the support package

Comment: Tried, doesn't help & I am sure they are from support package

Answer (score 1):

```
mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) content.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

should be

```
mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) content.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
```

and in the xml layout you should specify

```
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
```

as

```
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution, now it doesn't throw ClassCastException, but the mTabHost is null.

Comment: @Mellon that's what I found too. Actually my experience is reverse of Campig, where I started with findViewById(R.id.tabhost) and android:id="@+id/tabhost" being null, to the instantiated TabHost.  Yours is a recent question, only a month old. This is possibly a new bug in Eclipse or the ADT.